JAVA_HOME environment variable missing in github actions runner
I am trying to run java setup and then lein setup, where java setup run successfully.
We are getting problem to run java required next step.
- name: Set up JDK 17     
  uses: actions/setup-java@v4
  with:
        java-version: '17'
        distribution: 'temurin'
- name: Use oxr463/setup-leiningen  // this step needs java 
  uses: oxr463/setup-leiningen@0.0.1
  with:
    exec: |
          lein uberjar && \
          cp "$(find . -name '*.jar')" .

Error at after the workflow run :
/usr/local/bin/lein: line 224: type: java: not found

Leiningen couldn't find 'java' executable, which is required.

Please either set JAVA_CMD or put java (>=1.6) in your $PATH (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin).

/usr/local/bin/lein: line 224: type: java: not found

Leiningen couldn't find 'java' executable, which is required.

Please either set JAVA_CMD or put java (>=1.6) in your $PATH (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin).

Am I missing any step? Please do suggest the solution.

After actions/setup-java@v4 step, java command should already be available. The examples in its docs reflect this. You can verify that by running java -version in a separate step after actions/setup-java step.

I've checked one my own action runs, the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set. I can run mvn successfully. However, I've never tried running java. Can you add a step between these two that simply runs env | sort? That will show you all environment variables. The PATH entry is particularly interesting. It's possible that $JAVA_HOME/bin isn't added to it.

Try setting the JAVA_CMD environment variable to the path of the Java executable. This might help Leiningen locate the Java installation.
env:
          JAVA_CMD: $(which java)  # Set JAVA_CMD to the path of the Java executable


thank you , however its not working . Issue still exist

This step to adding env variable did not work for me  :
- name: Set  JAVA_CMD env           run: echo "JAVA_CMD=$(echo $JAVA_HOME )/bin" >> $GITHUB_ENV        - name: Test JAVA_CMD        run: echo $JAVA_CMD
